# Write an e-mail to reply for a changed planing

Tags: email

I have write an email to replay on a changed planing sent by my english school and why i can't come.

this is bellow what i wrote but i didn't send it yet, any correction or something to add or any inappropriate expression ?

Mr. Julio,

I am writing with regard to the next programed session that will take place on sunday 27th to inform you that's confusing with another pre-programed trip outside of France.

I would like to be present and assist to the complet session, but as you know, it will be impossible.

Hoping that my sincere apologies will be kindly accepted

i miss the endining of the email and i dont know to end it (any expression please)

Thanks

Comment: It is off topic to proof-read here. Can you first try installing a spell checker in your browser? It will at least highlight the lower case personal pronouns "i" which must ALWAYS be a capital letter "I"

Comment: Sorry, but i have a frensh browser, this is why it doesn't correct

Comment: @archavin Don’t blame the software for your mistakes.

Comment: @tchrist i'm sorry for the error, i will install english version next time

Comment: I have French, German, Dutch, Danish, UK and US English running in my browser spellchecker :)

Comment: @mplungjan i never heared that before :) could you give us which browser you use ?

Comment: [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker)  and [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way you might want to consider.

> Dear Mr. Julio,
>
> I am writing with regard to the next programmed session that will take place on
>
> Sunday 27th.
>
> Be advised that I already have a trip outside France preprogrammed on that date.
>
> I wish I could be present and assist at the complete session, but, due to the date conflict, I am
>
> afraid it will not be possible.
>
> Please accept my apology.
>
> Sincerely,

Comment: Hmm, I do not see much difference to my version - not to mention I spent time correcting your actual question too

Answer (score 0):

It is off topic to proof read, but the whole question needs to be run through at least a spell checker.

I have *written* an email to *reply to* a changed *planning* sent by my *English* school to *explain* why ***I*** can't come.

*Below is* what ***I*** wrote but ***I*** didn't send it yet. *Are there* any *corrections needed* or something to add or any inappropriate *expressions* ?

***I*** miss the *ending* of the email and ***I*** *don't* know *how* to end it

> Mr. Julio,
>
> I am writing with regards to the next programmed session that will take place on Sunday 27th to inform you that it is in conflict with another pre-programmed trip outside France.
>
> I would like to be present and assist at the complete session, but due to the conflict, it will be impossible.
>
> Hoping my sincere apologies will be kindly accepted
>
> Best regards,
> .....

Comment: You are welcome. Here is how to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)